# I have a 2 stage Goodman GMH80803BN Can someone tell me the correct dip switch settings for 2 stage? I have an ECOBEE Thermostate

Tags: furnace

[image]

Wiring diagram on inside cover

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Can you post a fully-lit picture? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: In the installer section it says _Note: This furnace is designed for use with a single stage room thermostat._ . That, and your question is a little unclear.  We need more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You have two options for two stage. One option is on low for five minutes then kicks over to high, the other option is on low for a variable time 1 to 12 minutes then kicks over to high.